# woocommerce get list of attribute values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce on wordpress to create a simple shop site and I've added a couple attributes to a product. These are namely, `size` and `color`. Under size I have a variety of values including Small, Medium and Large. Same with color ie. Red, Blue, Green.

What I want to do is show these values in a dropdown. Basically just list them out so I can use the values as filters for the shop catalog page.

Any help would be great.

EDIT:
I've delved into the woocommerce code and api docs and only found this code to pull the attributes.

```
global $woocommerce;

$attr_tax = $woocommerce->get_attribute_taxonomy_names();

foreach( $attr_tax as $tax ) {
     echo $woocommerce->attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name );
}
```

What this snippet gives me are the taxonomy slugs only, ie. pa_size and pa_color. I'm very new to woocommerce, but a search in there api docs reveals nothing about how to pull the values of these attributes.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this at all?

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry. I forgot to post my code.

Comment: There is a much simpler way then to use code to do what you want. A woocommerce product can be a variable product and from there you can set the fields you want to have as a variable. Here is a link to some documentation for it: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `get_terms()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

If you pass in pa_size or pa_color you will get back a list of terms in that taxonomy.

Comment: Works great! Moreover, the returned array is sorted according to the custom order if used.

Answer (score 18):

Hoping this is helpful to someone:

```
global $product; 

// Get product attributes
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if ( ! $attributes ) {
    echo "No attributes";
}

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

        echo $attribute['name'] . ": ";
        $product_attributes = array();
        $product_attributes = explode('|',$attribute['value']);

        $attributes_dropdown = '<select>';

        foreach ( $product_attributes as $pa ) {
            $attributes_dropdown .= '<option value="' . $pa . '">' . $pa . '</option>';
        }

        $attributes_dropdown .= '</select>';

        echo $attributes_dropdown;
}
```

Comment: This surely can be helpful to someone. But who? And how? What does this code do? Make it mor eclear wit ha bit of explanation or comments in the code :)

Comment: OP is asking for a list of all attributes. Your solution is only on a single product level.

Comment: @Bjorn you sure like saying that

Answer (score 7):

This post was written some time ago so I don't know if Woocommerce had this method in its previous incarnations.
For anyone else looking to do this, this line is all you need.

```
$product->list_attributes();
```

This allows you to customize the order and toggle whether or not you want to display the variation in the backend,

Comment: Is there a way to put these in an array and only call one or two?

Comment: OP is asking for a list of all attributes. Your solution is only on a single product level.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @user5029040 answer, which outputs html, if you want to get an array you can use the following function.

```
$product->get_variation_attributes();
```

Comment: Doesn't work outside of the loop: `Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_variation_attributes()`

Comment: OP is asking for a list of all attributes. Your solution is only on a single product level.

Comment: @AlexanderHolsgrove This method is defined for `WC_Product_Variation`, not `WC_Product_Simple`. https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_product_variationget_variation_attributes/

Comment: If you don’t have the right `$product` in your scope, there is also `wc_get_product_variation_attributes()` which requires just the product ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to retrieve all of the values for every wc taxonomy.

You could use the function: `wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()`. This will return an array like:

```
[
  "id:24" => {
    "attribute_id": "24"
    "attribute_name": "bending-lines"
    "attribute_label": "Bending lines"
    "attribute_type": "select"
    "attribute_orderby": "menu_order"
    "attribute_public": "0"
  }
]
```

Then you could use the function `get_terms()` to retrieve the values per taxonomy.

Comment: Extra tip: when using `get_terms()` and specifying a `taxonomy` value, you have to prepend `pa_` to the `attribute_name` returned by `wc_get_attribute_taxonomis()`, OR use the built-in function `wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( "attribute_name" )` to get it automatically :)

Comment: Good one! Have forgot about that a few times haha